# express redirect error Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

```js
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/todo-list')
  Todo.find({completed: false}, function (err, todos) {
    if (err) throw err
    res.render('homepage', {
      allTodos: todos
    })
    mongoose.disconnect()
  })
})
//
app.post('/create', function (req, res) {
  // console.log(req.body)
  // res.send(req.body)
  todosController.create(req, res)
})

app.get('/listall', function (req, res) {
  res.redirect('/listall')
  todosController.list(req, res)
})
// and below is my controller

function list (req, res) {
  if (!mongoose.connection.db) mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/todo-list')
  Todo.find({}, function (err, todos) {
    if (err) throw err
    res.render('listall', {
      allTodos: todos
    })
    mongoose.disconnect()
  })
}
```

can someone tell me how to fix this >.<
express shows error "Can't set headers after they are sent."
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:371:11)

Comment: this is common error, when you already sent response via `end`, `send`, `sendStatus`, `json`, `render` or `redirect`, but after that you trying to send something again.
So after `res.redirect`, you can't do anything and send response again.
can you show your todosController?

Comment: FYI, `if (err) throw err` inside an async callback does nothing useful.  That exception can't be caught anywhere as it just goes back inside your database.  Please code real error handling.

Comment: FWIW, only call `mongoose.connect()` at the top level of your app, and don't call `mongoose.disconnect()`.

Comment: thank you all i understand it clearer :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from trying to send request to user twice (via render and redirect), here:

```
app.get('/listall', function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('/listall')
    todosController.list(req, res)
})
```

Youredirect user to listall view, but then you are invoking list method, which tries to render another page here:

```
res.render('listall', {
  allTodos: todos
})
```

You have to decide, if you want to redirect user to page, or render it to him, and remove one of those above.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to remove this line and your /listall route should work:

```
res.redirect('/listall')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `todosController.list(req, res)` seems to have also a res.send/res.redirect ... method. But you can only send a response once so if there are other res. methods in your request flow you get this error.

You can redirect the user from your todosController.list method and remove it from here `app.get('/listall', function (req, res) {
  res.redirect('/listall')
  todosController.list(req, res)
})`

But take care not to send res. more than once in one single req. flow.